# extract incremental changes to directory

Tags: osx, directory, rsync, backup

I would like to get *only* the differential backup of a single directory, using cmdline tools on OSX (to be run on a Continuous-Integration service)

Basically, i have a directory full of things (files and subdirs with files and subdirs,...), and a job that is adding more things to this directory.
once the job has completed, i'd like to to extract all the new files added by the job.
(The job is `brew` installing some additional software to `/usr/local`; I would like to extract all the *additional* software installed).

On linux, i would use `GNU-tar` with something like this:

```
 tar --create --file /dev/null --listed-incremental=data.snar ${BACKUPDIR}
 # run the job
 ...
 tar -cz --file backup.tgz --listed-incremental=data.snar ${BACKUPDIR}
```

Unfortunately this is on OSX, so i only have `BSD-tar` which lacks the `--listed-incremental` flag.

I also thought about using `rsync`, with something like:

```
rsync --delete --backup --backup-dir=backup.0 -a ${BACKUPDIR} /tmp/backup/
# run the job
...
rsync --delete --backup --backup-dir=backup.1 -a ${BACKUPDIR} /tmp/backup/
```

However, this seems to not do what i expected: if the job deletes files, these end up in the directory speficied with `--backup-dir`, but i never see **only** the files added by the job...

I really would like to have a solution that does **not** require me to install *any* additional software (including GNU-tar), as this most likely interferes with the actual data-directory that I would like to get the differences for (`/usr/local/`).

Comment: You don't like to use GNU tar for incremental backups since GNU tar is unable to do incremental restores for incrementals with non-trivial deltas. The related bugs have been reported in 2004, 2011, 2016 and 2018 to no avail. There seems even no interest in fixing the bugs.

Answer (score -1):

Use GNU tar on macosx. It is based on the same source.
http://macappstore.org/gnu-tar/

Comment: thanks but no. i edited my question to clarify that i don't want to install *any* additional software (esp. using `brew`)

Comment: Just for mention: your shellscript will be an additional software, too. ;->

Comment: fail enough :-) but then - there won't be a *script* to be run, just a line of code to be found in the CI-configuration and to be run by the CI.